# Tkinter how tout compare tags of canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

Heyy,
I have some issues with the tag system of Tkinter in Python 3.
I have a matrix of canvas "tile" and some of them have the "trap" tag.
How can I compare tag of each tiles of my matrix with the "trap" tag (I don't know how to write the condition, I know that I have to browse my matrix and compare each of them)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The following compares the tags for each item in your canvas and returns a list of all the item ids that have the "trap" tag.

```
traps = [item for item in canvas.find_all() if "trap" in canvas.itemcget(item, "tags")]
```

Here, `canvas.find_all()` returns the id for all the items in the canvas. `canvas.itemcget` gets the tags configuration information which is a list of tag names and we check to see if "trap" is a member of that list.

Generally you bind actions to the tags so for instance if you click an item with the trap tag you can perform some function. If using bound events (`canvas.tag_bind`) then you may not need to search all the items in the above manner.